# Cheapish wireless trigger for a Nissin Di866 on a Nikon D60

Tags: nikon, flash

I'm looking for a cheapish solution to triggering an off-camera flash. The camera is a Nikon D60 and the Flash a Nissin Di866 Pro.

So far I have not been able to find a suitable trigger. I'm hoping to pay < £40 (GB Pounds).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What remote flash triggers can you recommend, on a budget?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6573/what-remote-flash-triggers-can-you-recommend-on-a-budget)

Answer (score 1):

There's a pretty good chance that the [CowboyStudio system](http://www.cowboystudio.com/product/c14/p140704-04.php) would work for you.

While your flash is not specifically listed as compatible, the trigger voltage is 3.5, well under the 12 V maximum, so it should work just fine.

These are not known to be as reliable as some of the top brands, but at the significantly lower cost, they are a great option, and tend to get good reviews.